# Can i disable sorting for grouped application in dash left menu?

Tags: unity

need solution for disable sorting "last application moved to up" in grouped application. 
i hate this ui, i think in 14 ubuntu this it was better 
(right click open a list of grouped apps, and not sorted by last used)

Answer (score 0):

That you hate the ui is obviously your personal appreciation. It might be a signal for you to try one of the many other desktop environments available, so you can settle on the one that suits your preferred workflow best.

Nevertheless, there is a lot about the Ubuntu Dock that can be changed under the hood. As such, you can change the behaviour of a left click on an item to instead show window previews if multiple applications are running. Issue the following command to get this in effect:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'previews'
```

Since Ubuntu 19.10, the order of the previews remains static, i.e. in the order opened. This is a big improvement over previous versions, where the previews would be in the order of most recently used.